# Use `.` syntax and `with = FALSE` in one data.table call

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I want to have a data.table that contains user supplied columns and programmer specified renaming, for example, the following code:

```
iris <- data.table::data.table(iris)
# details varies, users are smart and don't specify columns that will be renamed.
details <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')
cbind(iris[, .(Type = Species)], iris[, details, with = FALSE])
```

I'm interested in the most efficient and elegant method to select and rename the columns. What is it? We haven't been able to do better than the `cbind()` above. data.table is of a reasonable size, say 500.000 rows by 8 columns.

### Addendum

I've ran the solutions provided by Akrun with microbenchmark, they perform quite well:

```
> microbenchmark(
  cbind1 = cbind(iris3000[, .(Type = Species)], iris3000[, details, with = FALSE]),
  cbind2 = cbind(iris3000[, .(Type = Species)], iris3000[, ..details]),
  assignment = iris3000[, ..details][, Type := iris3000$Species][],
  setnames1 = setnames(iris3000[, .SD, .SDcols = c("Species", details)],  "Species", "Type")[],
  setnames2 = setnames(iris3000[,  c("Species", ..details)], 1, "Type")[],
  times = 500L
)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
     cbind1 4.900362 5.304078 6.306950 5.414371 5.558222  21.77936   500
     cbind2 4.910121 5.296428 6.720642 5.411720 5.514940 221.38992   500
 assignment 2.108325 2.284778 2.738970 2.333464 2.394961  18.55119   500
  setnames1 2.155007 2.372021 2.857554 2.423696 2.483803  20.26001   500
  setnames2 1.832926 2.048634 2.960401 2.095429 2.145081 204.90523   500
```

The case `details <- NULL` also works and is faster.

Comment: `with=FALSE` disables `with()`-like interface in `j` making data.table interface a data.frame like, so you cannot use `.()`, read more at `?with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns to select in `.SDcols`, subset the `.SD` and change the specific column name with `setnames`

```
setnames(iris[, .SD, .SDcols = c("Species", details)], "Species", "Type")[]
```

---

The OP's code using `with = FALSE` can be shortened to `..`

```
cbind(iris[, .(Type = Species)], iris[, ..details])
```

Or instead of `cbind`, can do an assignment

```
iris[, ..details][, Type := iris$Species][]
```

Or another option is

```
setnames(iris[,  c("Species", ..details)], 1, "Type")[]
#          Type Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#  1:    setosa          5.1         3.5
#  2:    setosa          4.9         3.0
#  3:    setosa          4.7         3.2
#  4:    setosa          4.6         3.1
#  5:    setosa          5.0         3.6
# ---                                   
#146: virginica          6.7         3.0
#147: virginica          6.3         2.5
#148: virginica          6.5         3.0
#149: virginica          6.2         3.4
#150: virginica          5.9         3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent, I didn't know about the `[]` trick. I've added benchmarks to the question to showcase your solutions. All improve upon our current code :)

Comment: Using `1L` in the last one seems to be slightly faster but it's only _slightly_.